# Preventing multiple JavaScript scripts loading in Asp.Net Core ViewComponents

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

For example, I have this `PrimitiveViewComponent`:

```
<button type="button" onClick="sayHello"></button>
<script>
    function sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello")
    }
</script>
```

If I invoke them more than once, like this:

```
<div>@await Component.InvokeAsync("Primitive")</div>
<div>@await Component.InvokeAsync("Primitive")</div>
<div>@await Component.InvokeAsync("Primitive")</div>
```

it would be an ambiguity, because the function `sayHello` would be included three times, which isn't necessary.

How should I define JavaScript functions for ViewComponents, how can I prevent them from being included more than once, and where to store them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way in server side to manage this issue. But using Javascript and JQuery you can fix this problem.

In this code, I moved the script to a file scripts.js under js folder in wwwroot. While loading the page I am checking whether the SayHello is a function or it is undefined, if it is a function means it is loaded to the page, if it is undefined, I am loading the script using JQuery getscript method.

Here is the view component code.

```
<button type="button" onClick="sayHello()">Hello</button>
<script>
    if (typeof sayHello !== 'function') {
        $.getScript( "/js/scripts.js" ).done(function( script, textStatus ) {
            console.log( textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Could `$.getScript( "/js/scripts.js" )`be potential security hole in my web application? If yes, how can we secure it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a property like **ScriptIncluded** to specify whether the script included in the model, and in server side to maintain the property status; Check the **ScriptIncluded** property whether true every time when invoke the component like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick="sayHello"></button>
@if(model.ScriptIncluded){
    <script>
        function sayHello(){
        }
    </script>
}
```

In your component class definition, you should set the `model.ScriptIncluded = True;` if the component is not invoked first time. You can keep a bool value in `HttpContext.Items`.